# Parsing a Large Text in Sections in Matlab

Tags: parsing, matlab, text

I have a large text file as below imported in `MATLAB`:

```
Run Lat Long Time
1 32 32 34
1 23 22 21
2 23 12 11
2 11 11 11
2 33 11 12
```

up to 10 runs etc.

So I'm trying to break up each section in the file: section 1, section 2, etc and write it to 10 different text files. File 1 will have data from Run 1. File 2 will have data from Run 2.

Comment: So is your data imported into matlab as you indicated, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [Matlab's textread function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textread.html).  I'll give you the pieces you need and frame out the logic, but you'll need to connect the pieces yourself :)

Your read would look something like this

```
[head1, head2, head3, head4] = textread(file_name,'%s %s %s %s',1);
[run, lat, long, time] = textread(file_name,'%u %u %u %u');
```

and your write method would use a loop to iterate over the values in

`unique(run)`

creating a file with

`fout = fopen([base_file_name_out num2str(run_number)]);`

and writing to it the values contained in

`lat_this_run=Lat(run==run_number);`

using the method

`fprintf(fout,'%u %u %u\n', lat_this_run, long_this_run, time_this_run)`

Comment: I'm having trouble with the looping part.                              I'm using a while loop and getl but no success.  Please Help!  Thanks for help.

Comment: Hmmm the main loop I mentioned was a loop to write the text, but getl is an input command so I will need more info.  If the second textread command is not reading in every line of data from file, you should try changing the command to `textread(file_name,'%u %u %u %u\n');`

Comment: I'm trying to categorize the data so all the Runs 1 are placed in one output file and all the Runs 2 are placed in another output file.

Comment: to get a list of unique list of runs you use the command `unique_runs=unique(runs);` then you create a for loop that goes `from run_num=1:length(unique_runs)` and then inside that loop you first create the file `fout=fopen(['run' num2str(unique_runs(run_num))]);` and then identify which rows belong to this row number by saying `rows_this_run=(row==unique_runs(run_num));` that identifies the rows that come from this run, and allows you to use logical indexing to print only those rows with a `fprintf(fout,'%u %u %u\n', lat(rows_this_run), long(rows_this_run), time(rows_this_run)); fclose(fout)`

Answer (score 0):

If your data is already loaded into matlab and named `A`, you could do:

```
>> a = max(A(:,1));
>> AA={};
>> for i = 1:a
     AA{i}=A(find(A(:,1)==i),:)
     name=sprintf('%d.txt',i);
     dlmwrite(name,AA{i},'\t');
   end
```

The output will be .txt files containing tab-delimited data.